# Spring Security with Angular Login Endpoint?

Tags: spring, angular, spring-security

I've been working through the [Spring tutorial for Spring Security](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/), and I'm a bit confused. So far, it got me to spin up a java app and an angular app. I created the java app using the initializer and I created the angular app using the angular CLI. The problem is that it mentions that when I "load the home page [I] should get a browser dialog asking for username and password". My app didn't do this. When I ran my java and angular and went to localhost it just took me right to my app.component page. 
I went on with the tutorial as normal and created an endpoint on my Java side to get a resource. When I make the get request from my angular code, in my network tab I see my get request which comes back with a status of 302 and no response data, and then it makes a second network call to a localhost:[port]/login (I didn't explicitly make this call in the angular). This call has a status of 200, but it fails when it tries to parse it. I looked at the response from my network tab and it looks like it tried to send the login page that the tutorial references before.

[image]

Is there something I need to do to link up the angular to know that i'm using Spring Security? I'm just using an ng serve to run the angular, and i'm just running the main of the java in my IDE (intelliJ)

I can include my package.json or pom.xml or anything else if that helps?

Thanks

**** EDIT ****

here is what the browser console comes back with:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

we have also implemented the security using spring security and angular js and we have faced the CORS(cross origin request source) error if you are facing the same problem then this can be solved by overriding the CORS configuration in your spring application.

Comment: it doesn't look like it's a CORS issue. I don't see anything complaining about the CORS in my console. I have a chrome plugin that toggles CORS and I tried it with it both toggled on and off and it didn't cause any differences.

Comment: I added my browser console to the question if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out their tutorial's way of spinning up an angular project is coupled with their maven Java build, so it does the npm and ng stuff when you build the java. I was running the angular independently, so when I ran the angular I was specifying a different port from my java and therefore wasn't getting the Spring login which was on the port my Java was running on.